# Using the Nest function -- Confusion on my output

Tags: functions, function-construction, syntax

I have the following code and output where the original function is $f(x,a) = a^2 - x^2$.

```
f[x_, a_] = a - x^2
ref := Nest[Function[{u, v}, f[u, v]][x, y], x, 2]
ref
(-x^2 + y)[(-x^2 + y)[x]]
```

I want the second iteration of this function. i.e, $f(f(x)) = a^2 - (a^2 - x^2)^2$. Why am I not getting this?

Comment: You need to use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) when you make the function assignement. `ref` on the other hand should be `Set` (`=`) since it will compute the same thing each time `ref` is called anyhow.

Comment: oh okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you give a 2-argument function as the first argument to `Nest`, but then only one expression.  From the documentation, I only see examples of `Nest` being given a single argument.

Here I use a single-argument function, since that seems to match the output you want,

```
f[x_, a_] = a^2 - x^2;
Nest[Function[x, f[x, a]], x, 2]
(* a^2 - (a^2 - x^2)^2 *)
```

Comment: Ah yep! That is what I was wanting. Thanks!

Comment: There were a couple more syntax problems with your input as well, like when you write `Function[{u, v}, f[u, v]]` that is a function that will take arguments, but when you put `[x,y]` after it, it's no longer a function since you are going to evaluate it already with `x` and `y` as the arguments.  Look at the syntax here and in the help file.  Marius's point about defining `f` with a `:=` is a valid one, but it is often okay to use `=` instead, you just have to see where it will trip you up.

Comment: @Ozera , go ahead and take the [tour](mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) here, and see this [thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) for good pointers.

Comment: Thank you both for the information! Learning mathematica is an interesting experience indeed.