# Trouble creating a bifurcation diagram of a trajectory

Tags: plotting, functions

I wish to create a bifurcation diagram of the trajectory made by $f(x,a) = a - x^2$ which shows the tangent bifurcation point and the period doubling point.

The tangent bifurcation point occurs at $\{a \to -\frac{1}{4}, x \to -\frac{1}{2}\}$ and the period doubling point at $\frac{1}{2}(1 \pm \sqrt[]{-3+4a})$. I've already found the stability for equilibrium points for $f$ and period-2 equilibrium points. Now I wish to make a bifurcation plot to see all of this information together, but I do not know how to do this.

I was trying to figure it out and came up with the following code, but it doesn't really match what I am wanting since it is just a trajectory plot.

```
traj[x_,a_] = NestList[f, x, 200];

Manipulate[ListPlot[traj[x,a], PlotRange -> All, {{x, -0.5}, -1, 1}, 
{{a, -0.25}, -0.26, 2}  ] ]
```

Can anyone show me how to create an actual bifurcation diagram for my function?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, how did you define `f`? And the right bracket of `ListPlot` is lost and there's a redundant right bracket at the end of the code. (Update: just read your [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108322/1871), you should have read the answer and comments more carefully, if you have difficulty in understanding them, simply go on asking in the comment. )

Comment: Try adjusting the code [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107731/how-to-create-a-version-of-fixedpointlist-for-asymptotically-periodic-functions/107733).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, you didn't show a *Mathematica* definition of `f`. Moreover, the definitions of `traj` is incorrect, and the syntax of `Manipulate` is wrong. Here's a corrected, complete version:

```
 f[x_, a_] := a - x^2
 traj[x_, a_] = NestList[f[#, a] &, x, 200];
 Manipulate[
    ListPlot[traj[x, a], PlotRange -> All],
    {{x, -0.5}, -1, 1}, {{a, -0.25}, -0.26, 2}
 ]
```

Since `NestList` is to act only upon the second argument `x` to `f`, then you need to fix the first argument `a` there, which is the reason for the change to the first argument of `NestList` so as to be `f[#, a]&` rather than just `f` (which has two arguments).

In your `Manipulate`, you misplaced the right bracket `]` that matches the left bracket `[` of `ListPlot`. The control variable expressions for the `Manipulate` need to go outside the `ListPlot` expression, not inside it.

To display the current values of the controls `a` and `x`, you might want to include the `Appearance -> "Labeled" option for each of the them:

```
 f[x_, a_] := a - x^2
 traj[x_, a_] = NestList[f[#, a] &, x, 200];
 Manipulate[
    ListPlot[traj[x, a], PlotRange -> All],
    {{x, -0.5}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
    {{a, -0.25}, -0.26, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

You probably also want to alter the initial value and lower bound of `a`, because you'll too easily get computational overflow at that initial value, and nearby values, if you decrease the value of `x` below its initial value.  Or at least trap the troublesome values.

Answer (score 4):

Just for something else:

```
f[x_, a_] := a - x^2;
cw[x_, a_, n_] := Module[{i = 0, nl, ln, tr},
  nl = NestWhileList[(i++; {#[[2]], f[#[[2]], a]}) &, {x, f[x, a]}, 
    And[i != n, Abs[#[[2]]] < 100] &];
  ln = Line[{#1, {#1[[2]], #1[[2]]}, #2}] & @@@ 
    Partition[nl, 2, 1]; {ln, nl[[All, 2]]}]
Manipulate[
 Module[{res = cw[x0, a, 100]}, 
  Row[{Show[Plot[{f[x, a], x}, {x, -1, 1}], 
     Graphics[res[[1, 1 ;; Min[20, Length@res[[1]]]]]], 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> 300], 
    ListPlot[res[[2]], Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]}]], {{a, 0.01}, -0.27, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{x0, 0.1}, -1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is so nice! Very insightful for what is happening with the trajectory.

Answer (score 3):

A common way to plot bifurcation diagrams is with the parameter on the horizontal axis and the values of the stable periodic orbits on the vertical. For the function f[k] = a-f[k-1]^2, this can be done as

```
Clear[f, a];
f[a_, n_] := f[a, n] = a - f[a, n - 1]^2;
f[a_, 1] = 0.5;
all = Flatten[Table[seq = f[aa, #] & /@ Range[10000];
    seq1000 = Union[seq[[9900 ;; 10000]]];
    Thread[{ConstantArray[aa, Length[seq1000]], seq1000}], 
           {aa, -0.2, 2, 0.01}], 1];
ListPlot[all, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]